# Why don't lists in python have a __dict__ attribute?

Tags: python, list, time-complexity

In order to decrease time complexity in python of:

```
if value in list:
    # Do something
```

You could make python lists have a `__dict__` attribute with each value of the list as a key and every value in the dict a `1` to make the time complexity of checking if a value is in a list `O(1)`.

For example, the `__dict__` attribute of the list:

```
["Hello", "World", "This", "Is", "An", "Example"]
```

Would look like this:

```
{"Hello": 1, "World": 1, "This": 1, "Is": 1, "An": 1, "Example": 1}
```

I tried accessing the `__dict__` attribute of a list in python and it gave me an `AttributeError`.

I expected this to be the case
I am surprised that it is not

Comment: If you want the O(1) features of dict, you would just use a dict. Lists are good at being lists so they should ... do that. :)

Comment: `__dict__` doesn't come for free; lists already take up a lot of memory, and this would add O(n) more memory on top of that. If you really need an ordered, random-access sequence with O(1) membership testing, you can implement that yourself. That's on top of the fact that what you are proposing has nothing to do with how every other type uses `__dict__`: you want value cache, not a set of instance attributes. Changing the name would also free you to use the data type that's really appropriate here: a set.

Comment: @KennyOstrom or, without the key:value pairs, a `set()`

Comment: And finally, list elements aren't necessarily hashable, which both `dict` and `set` require their elements to be.

Comment: Even if `list` objects had a `__dict__` attribute, it wouldn't contain the values in the list, since those values aren't *attributes of the list at all*. The `__dict__` of an object is it's *namespace* that maps attribute names to values. As to why this isn't implemented this way, because it would be hugely wasteful. You can always create such a dict yourself, or just use a `set`. The whole point of having specialized data structures is so that the programmer can choose to use the appropriate one for a given use-case.

Comment: Just to clarify chepner and juanpa's comments, if you do `a.b`, `b` is an *attribute* of `a`; if you do `a[b]`, `b` is an *index* of `a`.

Comment: Sure, dict/set can do some amazing things, but I'm a little disappointed nobody mentioned all the stuff lists are better at, and stuff that set/dict can't do. Long story short, choose the right data structure for the job.

Answer (score 2):

You can get what you want by using a set.

```
>>> "Hello" in {"Hello", "World", "This", "Is", "An", "Example"}
True
```

You get a O(1) lookup because sets and dictionaries are implemented as hash tables. This requires that all the keys in the dict or values in the set are immutable and hashable. Python lists are more flexible. Values can be mutable, they can be other lists, and you can even have cyclical references.

If every list had a built in hash table, there would be a significant performance and memory cost. So just use a set instead if you want a fast membership test.

If you already have a list, you can easily convert it to a set:

```
>>> my_list = list('hello world')
>>> set(my_list)
{'h', 'd', 'w', 'e', 'r', 'o', 'l', ' '}
>>> {*my_list}
{'h', 'd', 'w', 'e', 'r', 'o', 'l', ' '}
```

(Unpacking an iterable with `*` in a set literal requires python 3.5)

Answer (score 0):

Because nothing in software engineering is free. There is a cost to getting O(1) lookups.

Python dictionaries are implemented as hash tables and Python lists are actually dynamic arrays. Your implementation would force each python list to maintain a hash table and a dynamic array, since it would need to keep track of the order of the list.

Hash tables achieve O(1) lookups essentially by being wasteful with space. When you use a hash table you are trading space for speed. You may only have 100 items in your hash table but it is taking up more than 100 items worth of space, maybe 2x more -- anyway some constant factor more. But you get O(1) lookups ... so this is a good trade if you care more about O(1) lookups than you do about wasting memory. It is a bad trade if you do not care about O(1) lookups at all.

You would not want to do this in all cases because in many situations you do not care about testing for list inclusion in O(1) time.